# Python plot amount of x values in data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a huge csv file of data, it looks like this:

```
STAID,    SOUID,    DATE,   TX, Q_TX
   162,100522,19010101,  -31,    0
   162,100522,19010102,  -13,    0
```

TX is temperature, data goes on for a few thousand more lines to give you an idea.

For every year, I want to plot the amount of days with a temperature above 25 degrees.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("klimaat.csv")

zomers = data.index[data["TX"] > 250].tolist()

x_values = []
y_values = []
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.ylabel("Amount of days with TX > 250")
plt.title("Zomerse Dagen Per Jaar")
plt.plot(x_values, y_values)

# save plot
plt.savefig("zomerse_dagen.png")
```

X-axis should be the years say 1900-2010 or something, and the y-axis should be the amount of days with a temperature higher than 250 in that year.

How do I go about this? >_< I can't quite get a grasp on how to extract the amount of days from the data.... and use it in a plot.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the data points separately to make it a little easier to comprehend. Then use pandas.pivot_table to aggregate. Here is a working example that should get you going.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("klimaat.csv", parse_dates=["DATE"])
data.sort_values("DATE", inplace=True)
data["above_250"] = data.TX > 250
data["year"] = data.apply(lambda x: x["DATE"].year, axis=1).astype("category")

plot_df = pd.pivot_table(data, index="year", values="above_250", aggfunc="sum")

years = plot_df.index
y_pos = np.arange(len(years))
values = plot_df.above_250

plt.bar(y_pos, values, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, years)
plt.ylabel("Amount of days with TX > 250")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.title("Zomerse Dagen Per Jaar")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datetime` module from the python standard library to parse the dates, in particular, have a look at the [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) function. You can then use the `datetime.year` attribute to aggregate your data.

You can also use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to keep track of your aggregation before you assign `OrderedDict.keys()` and `OrdredDict.values()` to `x_values` and `y_values` respectively.